# How to use month and year in to_char in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

Quick help on this line of my code in my oracle database. So, I have a to_char with sysdate. However, I want to change the sysdate to say Jul-2020 but for some reason it tells me invalid number. Can anyone help me solve this small issue? thanks for the help.

here is what I have:

**Before:**

```
to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')
```

**After:**

```
to_char('Jul-2020', 'MM-YYYY'
```

Comment: 'Jul-2020' is already a string ("character" type), so why would you ever call `to_char` on it? What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Describe it in words, without any reference to code. For example: "I start with a **string** like 'Jul-2020' which represents a month and year, and I need to extract the year, also as a **string** (not as a **number**)". Or whatever the real task is. Do state the data type for the input and the output. Do **not** include any reference to **how** you think the task should be performed (`to_char()` or anything else).

Comment: correct. You got the described question right. As long I can printed result will say 2020.

Comment: Then why not just extract the last four characters? `substr(<input>, -4)` will read the substring starting at character position -4 (meaning, fourth character but counting backwards from the **end** of the string) - isn't that exactly what you need?

Comment: not quite. But, at first I was using sysdate and now I want to hard code to say jul-2020

Comment: You can't. `sysdate` is **date** data type. `'Jul-2020'` is **varchar2** data type, it is not **date** data type (even though the string "represents" a date). You could convert the string to a date first, and then use the same function you did for `sysdate` - but **WHY**? You say "not quite" - that doesn't explain why you can't do what I suggested. Why "not quite"?

Comment: basically, I just want to harcode my own date, is it possible?

Comment: Why did you only have `YYYY` with sysdate but then `MM-YYYY` with hardcoded value?

Comment: Yes, it is possible - but 'Jul-2020' is a hardcoded string, not a hardcoded date. If you want your own hardcoded date, you must do something like `to_char(date '2020-07-12', 'YYYY')` or if you want to have 'Jul-2020' in there, `to_char(to_date('Jul-2020', 'Mon-YYYY'), 'YYYY')`

Comment: dont know my old teammate had that store in there....

Comment: `to_char(date '2020-07-12', 'YYYY')` -- worked..... thank you

Comment: If you are dealing with a constant in your query, then I don't see why you make it this complicated. `to_char(date '2020-07-12', 'YYYY')` is equal to a mere `'2020'`, so why not directly use this string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is first you have let the dB know "Jul-2020" is a date format so the correct line should be to_char(to_date('Jul-2020','Mon-yyyy'), 'MM-YYYY')

Comment: i get "value too large...." error?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work as long as you provide input dates as below. You just need to be consistent, meaning you can't do `2020-July` without changing output format to `YYYY-MM`

```
select to_char(to_date('07-2020','MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY') from dual;

select to_char(to_date('July-2020','MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

If you want to be able to use both sysdate and hardcoded values inter-changeably, you can provide date in a specific format that works for sysdate and hardcoded date

```
select to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY') from dual;

select to_char(to_date('01-07-2020','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY') from dual;

select to_char(to_date('01-July-2020','DD-MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY') from dual
```